# Iterating over the table with recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, postgresql-9.4

I have the following data:

```
cte1
=================
gp_id | m_ids
------|----------
1     | {123}
2     | {432,222}
3     | {123,222}
```

And a function `foobar(m_ids integer[])`. The function contains the following cte:

```
with RECURSIVE foo as (
    select id, p_id, name from bar where id = any(m_ids)
    union all
    select b.id, b.p_id, b.name from bar b join foo f on f.p_id = b.id
)
```

The function is being used kind of like this:

```
select foobar(m_ids) from cte1;
```

Now, as a part of a process of improving performance, I was told to get rid of the function. My plan was to use cte `foo` in my cte chain, but I stuck trying to adjust usage of `any(m_ids)`.

***EDITED:***  To be clear, the problem is that `m_ids` that are used in the `where id = any(m_ids)` statement is the parameter of the function, so I got to transform cte in order to make it work outside of the function.

I thought of the following:

```
with RECURSIVE foo as (
    select (select id, p_id, name from bar where id = any(cte1.m_ids)
    union all
    select b.id, b.p_id, b.name from bar b join foo f on f.p_id = b.id)
    from cte1
)
```

But that would not work because
1) `recursive query "foo" does not have the form non-recursive-term UNION [ALL] recursive-term`
2) `subquery must return only one column`

In the end, I would like to get my data in the form like this:

```
m_ids    |foobar_result 
---------|-------------
{123}    | 125        
{432,222}| 215
```

Comment: Why can't you just copy that CTE without any changes? You don't explain it anywhere in your question. We also don't see whole body of function so can't say how to get desired result. What was your reasoning behind that subselect? What were you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I cant just copy CTE because in the `where id = any(m_ids)` statement m_ids is the parameter that being passed in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `JOIN` that table holding parameter?

```
with RECURSIVE foo as (
    select m_ids, id, p_id, name from bar
    JOIN cte1 ON id = ANY(m_ids)
    union all
    select m_ids, b.id, b.p_id, b.name from bar b join foo f on f.p_id = b.id
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel akward for not thinking of join myself :D